# How to split the arguments of a command over multiple lines

Tags: macros, formatting, parameters

I've defined a `newcommand` to create a reusable "requirement" component for my LaTeX document. The problem I have is that it seems like I need to have the entire command on a single line, which makes it super-unreadable.

This is how I want to write it:

```
\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{
    \vspace{1cm}
    \large\textsf{\textbf{#1}}

    \textsc{Type: #2 | Supported by: #3}

    \textsf{Description:}

    #4

    \textsf{Justification:}

    #5
}

\requirement
{R1: Should display available products}
{MVP}
{Interview with client}
{At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the available products.}
{Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}
```

But compiling it gives the error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.1348 \{R1:
```

And currently the only way I know to make it compile is to put everything on one line:

```
\requirement{R1: Should display available products}{MVP}{Interview with client}{At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the available products.}{Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}
```

This example is a short one, some requirements might have hundreds of words, meaning a single line will be ridiculously long. **Is there a way to split the parameters to commands over multiple lines?**

### Edit

For some reason (don't ask me why) I left out the fact that I'm compiling my document with Pandoc, and by looking at some answers here it seems that Pandoc is what's causing the "line splitting" to not work. I still have not resolved this though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Do give

```
\requirement%
{R1: Should display available products}%
{MVP}%
{Interview with client}%
{At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid 
 displaying the available products.}%
{Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}
```

While you're at it, do please also change

```
\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{
```

to

```
\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{%
```

---

A full minimum working example -- note that I've applied a few additions of the basic housekeeping variety to your code -- and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{%
\begingroup
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \par\noindent
    {\large\textsf{\textbf{#1}}\par}

    \textsc{Type: #2 | Supported by: #3}

    \textsf{Description:}

    #4

    \textsf{Justification:}

    #5
\endgroup\par\vspace{1cm}
}

\begin{document}

\requirement
{R1: Should display available products}
{MVP}
{Interview with client}
{At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the available products.}
{Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, this is the compiled result: https://imgur.com/QBR4yOb

Comment: @AxelKennedal - Well, it works *just fine* on my system, which uses the basic `article` document class. If my suggestion doesn't work on yours, it must be the case that there's important information about your document setup that you haven't shared so far. Please provide a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: I'm using Pandoc to write LaTeX mixed with Markdown, so I guess Pandoc introduces this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you had a completely blank line inside one of the arguments or between two arguments. A completely blank line (not counting spaces) turns into a `\par`. A single newline just turns into a space, so is no problem for your arguments (spaces between normal arguments are ignored).

So, you can split them across lines just fine, e.g., with:

```
\requirement
{R1: Should display available products}
{MVP}
{Interview with client}
{At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the available products.}
{Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}
```

The following would be fine as well:

```
\requirement
  {R1: Should display available products}
  {MVP}
  {Interview with client}
  {%
    At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the
    available products.%
  }
  {Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}
```

(note that I used a `%` to remove the space at the start and end of the fourth argument, which would be caused by the newline)

And you can ignore an otherwise blank line by putting a `%` in it, so the following works as well, as there are no implicit `\par` tokens (the `%` doesn't have to be the first thing in the line, spaces at the start of a line are ignored, just putting `%` in the line removes the `\par`):

```
\requirement
  %
  {R1: Should display available products}
  %
  {MVP}
  %
  {Interview with client}
  %
  {%
    At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the
    available products.%
  }
  %
  {Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}
```

---

Please note that your usage of `\large` in the code you provided is wrong, `\large` has to be put into a scope if you don't want to turn the rest of the current group/document into `\large`. Also, I'd use explicit `\par` tokens in the definition of a macro, instead of two consecutive newlines:

```
\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{%
    \vspace{1cm}%
    {\large\textsf{\textbf{#1}}\par}%
    \textsc{Type: #2 | Supported by: #3}\par
    \textsf{Description:}\par
    #4\par
    \textsf{Justification:}\par
    #5\par
}
```

---

You might want to consider using a `description` environment for your output. The following uses `enumitem` to customise the used `description` environment.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\requirement[5]
  {%
    \vspace{1cm}%
    {\large\sffamily\bfseries#1\par}%
    \textsc{Type: #2 | Supported by: #3}\par
    \begin{description}[font=\normalfont\sffamily,nosep,style=nextline]
      \item[Description:] #4
      \item[Justification:] #5
    \end{description}%
  }

\begin{document}

\requirement
  {R1: Should display available products}
  {MVP}
  {Interview with client}
  {%
    At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the
    available products.%
  }
  {Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the OP defined the `\requirement` macro to be "long", the presence of implicit or explicit paragraph breaks in one or more of the command's five required arguments shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Mico correct. But the used `\textbf`, `\textsc` and friends aren't long, and that's where the error is thrown, so one of the parameters `#1`, `#2`, or `#3` contained the `\par` and erred as a result.

Comment: The OP's uses of `\textbf`, `\textsf`, and `\textsc` don't appear to include any -- explicit or implicit -- paragraph breaks. Or am I maybe missing something? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico not as stated in the question itself, no. But if you take a look at the error message OP shows, that one gives it away (`Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete`), so I guess he left a blank line either after `\requirements`, or after the first or second argument.

Comment: As I've already stated in the question, splitting the arguments across lines does not work for me. After reading another answer here I suspect it might be that Pandoc (which I'm using) is inserting `\par` automatically somehow somewhere. @Skillmon

Comment: @AxelKennedal then show a minimal but complete example of your Pandoc document in your question, not some code snippets which work as you show them if used in LaTeX!

Comment: @AxelKennedal and the next time, say that you're using Pandoc right from the start, not just when several answers are provided and you realise that none of them contain the actual answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah true, I should have included that, I expected that a LaTeX solution would work for me but obviously that was not the case, my bad

Comment: On the bright side I realized that Pandoc seems to be the issue ‍♂️ And I learned a lot from your answer, so thanks :)

Comment: @AxelKennedal Pandoc tries to be convenient, as a result a `{` is translated to `\{` in LaTeX, for example, as well as `%`, that is translated to `\%`. I'm not that experienced with Pandoc, tbh., but I'm pretty sure that you have to somehow escape the LaTeX block if you need LaTeX syntax (if that's even possible at all).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way your code can produce the error. The error can be reproduced almost the same by typing

```
\requirement

{R1: Should display available products}
{MVP}
{Interview with client}
{At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the available products.}
{Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}
```

---

On the other hand, your code is weak under many respects.

1. You're declaring `\large` which will affect the whole document from the first call of `\requirement` on (bounded only by a group end).
2. All paragraphs are affected by the standard indentation; maybe you're setting `\parindent` to zero, but it would be better to state `\noindent` anyway.
3. `\vspace` is best issued *between* paragraphs; however, you should use `\addvspace`, so this wouldn't add to other vertical spaces defined with the same `\addvspace` macro (for instance after a section title).
4. Blank lines inside a definition can be used, but they make `\par` and you don't want page breaks in the middle of a requirement.

Here's a fixed version. You can type each argument in a new line, but leave ***no*** blank lines between arguments. Leaving a couple of spaces in front of each argument is, in my opinion, better, in order to ease reading the code.

I don't find 1cm a good spacing, where `\bigskipamount` would be probably better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\requirement}[5]{%
  \par% <--- very important
  \addvspace{1cm}% better than \vspace in this case
  \noindent{\large\textsf{\textbf{#1}}\par}\nopagebreak
  \noindent\textsc{Type: #2 | Supported by: #3}\\*
  \textsf{Description:}\\*
  #4\\*
  \textsf{Justification:}\\*
  #5\par
}

\begin{document}

\requirement
  {R1: Should display available products}
  {MVP}
  {Interview with client}
  {At the front page of the webshop there should be a grid displaying the available products.}
  {Users visiting the site need a way to discover products.}

\end{document}
```

[image]